# Spring, modelmap, getting attributes from the jsp

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I develop an MVC application with spring framework and some other frameworks (and I'm a beginner). I have a controller to manage jsp handling, for example when I want  add new person to my 'person list' I call a instantiate a person object and I pass it to the jsp view corresponding to the add method. And I do that by this a method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/persons/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAdd(Model model) {
    logger.debug("Received request to show add page");

    // Create new UserDomain and add to model
    // This is the formBackingOBject
    model.addAttribute("personAttribute", new UserDomain());

    // This will resolve to /WEB-INF/jsp/addpage.jsp
    return "addpage-tiles";
}
```

My problem is that now, I want to pass to add to the model two different Objects, for example, I want to pass the 'new UserDomain()' and also an other object which is from an other table in my database, for example a 'new UserSecurity()'.
I think I should use a 'modelMap' instead of the 'model.addAttribute...', but I can't do this, so if someone could help me.
I get my model from the jsp by a code like :

```
<form:form modelAttribute="personAttribute" method="POST" action="${saveUrl}">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="firstName">First Name:</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="firstName"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="lastName">Last Name</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="lastName"/></td>
    </tr>   
     <tr>
        <td><form:label path="userName">User name</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="userName"/></td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="email">E-mail</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="email"/></td>
    </tr>           
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
```

thank you a lot for helping me.

Comment: What's wrong with `model.addAttribute("userSecurity", new UserSecurity())`?

Comment: nothing is wrong, but in fact i can't use model.addAttribute("userSecurity", new UserSecurity()); and model.addAttribute("personAttribute", new UserDomain()); because in the jsp i can't write <form:form modelAttribute="personAttribute" modelAttribute="userSecurity" method="POST" action="${saveUrl}">. only one modelAttribute is allowed to be included in the jsp

Answer (score 3):

Simply passing more than one object to the view is not a problem -- just use `model.addAttribute` multiple times, and then you can access both objects.

However, if you want to edit more than one model in `<form:form>` you'll need to create a class that contains both of the objects:

```
public class UserDomainSecurity {

    private UserDomain userDomain;
    private UserSecurity userSecurity;

    // getters and setters for both

}
```

Then pass an instance of this into the view:

```
 model.addAttribute("userDomainSecurity", new UserDomainSecurity());
```

And use it in the form:

```
<form:form commandName="userDomainSecurity" method="POST" action="${saveUrl}">
...
  <form:input path="userDomain.firstName"/>
  ....
  <form:input path="userSecurity.someSecurityProperty"/>
```

It's sometimes annoying to have to create all these additional classes, but it is somewhat logical. The wrapper class creates kind of namespaces in the form and thus separates the individual objects that you want to edit.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add on this as it's really the present problem I have encountered minutes ago.

In this case, I assumed that you're `UserSecurity` and `UserDomain` are relative to each other.

Let say you have,

```java
public class UserDomain {

     public UserSecurity userSecurity
     public String firstName;
     public String lastName;

     // getters and setters...
}
```

and you have your UserSecurity something like,

```java
public class UserSecurity {

     public String someSecurityProperty;

     // getters and setters...
}
```

Since `userSecurity` property can be accessed publicly, then you can just do what you have did in your Controller,

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/persons/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAdd(Model model) {
logger.debug("Received request to show add page");

// Create new UserDomain and add to model
// This is the formBackingOBject
model.addAttribute("userDomainSecurity", new UserDomain());

// This will resolve to /WEB-INF/jsp/addpage.jsp
return "addpage-tiles";
}
```

then just access it in your addpage.jsp like it's an object property like below,

```
<form:form commandName="userDomainSecurity" method="POST" action="${saveUrl}">
...
<form:input path="firstName />
<form:input path="lastname />
  ....
  <form:input path="userSecurity.someSecurityProperty"/>
```

as you notice, I access the someSecurityProperty by the property declared in `UserDomain` class.